# Android emulator speed with nested KVM

Tags: android-emulator, kvm, android-x86

I am trying to run an Android emulator inside a virtual machine and would like to use KVM's nested support to speed up the emulator.

I run the emulator with `emulator64-x86 -avd test -qemu -m 1024 -enable-kvm` and I've made sure KVM nested support is available on both host and guest: `cat /sys/module/kvm_intel/parameters/nested` is "Y"

Still the emulator is slow, is there something I'm missing or a log file I can consult to see if nested support is in fact used at all?

Comment: I'm running into the same problem, did you find a solution already?

Comment: @C-Otto not yet, still looking for a solution, have you come up with a solution?

Comment: Not really, I decided to let this run on bare metal instead.

Comment: If you use Genymotion http://www.genymotion.com/ that problem will go away.

Comment: You must provide an x86-based AVD configuration name, otherwise VM acceleration will not be enabled. Also genymotion.com is another good choice.

Comment: Ofcourse I already provided an x86 based AVD config, otherwise emulator64-x86 would not work in the first place. I'm not looking for a paid solution like genymotion though.